# Debugging IE when shown within an Outlook plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, outlook, outlook-addin, internet-explorer-10

I am working on a web app in which part of will be shown inside Outlook Explorer using an Outlook plugin that opens an IE window **within Outlook**. I've had no problems with users that have IE 7,8 or 9 installed, however, if you have IE 10 installed you get a javascript error when loading the page. The same page loaded in IE10 outside of Outlook in the same environemnt has no errors unfortunately, so I can't use the IE dev tools, and hitting F12 while the Outlook IE window has focus unfortunately does nothing.

Does anyone know a way to be able to debug a page opened within Outlook? Either using an external tool that can hook into it or anything else? Ideally something realtime like Chrome's or even IE's tools that can break-point or even just show console logging if that's all I can get.

FYI: My testing env right now where I can reproduce this JS error is Outlook 2013 running on Windows 8. All I get from IE is the "Script error..." which gives me a line number and character to my minified JQuery script which does not help to find the actual cause of the issue.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio you should be able to attach its script debugger to outlook.exe.

Comment: @RichieHindle Do you know if I need a full version of VS to do that, or would I be able to use an Express such as Visual Studio Express for Web?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know (I only have the full version).

Comment: It doesn't look like it will work with Express, but I'll give it a try with Ultimate and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I was able to attach the VS debugger to Outlook.exe and I made sure that Break on all JS Runtime Exceptions was checked, but unfortunately when the error pops up I get no break or context within VS. Thanks for the help and suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use The [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) included in Windows 10 to develop and debug Office Add-ins.